# Multiple step Pandas processing with Airflow

Tags: pandas, airflow

I have a multiple stage ETL transform stage using pandas. Basically, I load almost 2Gb of data from Mongodb and then I apply several functions in the columns. My question is if there's any way to break those transformations in multiple Airflow tasks.

The options I have considered are:

1. Creating a temporary table in Mongodb and loading/storing the transformed data frame between steps. I found this cumbersome and totally prone to a non-usual overhead due to disk I/O
2. Passing data among the tasks using XCom. I think this is a nice solution but I worry about the sheer size of the data. The docs explicitly state

> Any object that can be pickled can be used as an XCom value, so users should make sure to use objects of **appropriate size.**

3. Using an in-memory storage between steps. Maybe saving the data in a Redis server or something, but I'm not really sure if that would be any better than just using XCom altogether.

So, does any of you have any tips on how to handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: Were you previously doing intermediate writes and reads for your transformations? If the data is stored in-memory it wouldn't make sense to split up your steps. You can write your Mongo query to a shared volume in one task, bunch up your Pandas transformations into another task and then write to your destination, then delete the temporary object in the final task.